# How to filter on criteria based on tags in Scala

Tags: scala, types

Given an object that has some 'typed' tags.
What's the best way to design the implementation of a matcher against some criteria. The question is really about leveraging the type system in an efficient manner.

Here is my current try :

```
 object Criteria1 extends App {

  // Features
  // Feature A
  trait A
  case object A1 extends A
  case object A2 extends A

  // Feature B
  trait B
  case object B1 extends B
  case object B2 extends B

  // Criteria
  trait Criteria
  case class ACriteria(a: Set[A]) extends Criteria
  case class BCriteria(b: Set[B]) extends Criteria

  // Tag
  trait Tag
  case class ATag(a: A) extends Tag
  case class BTag(b: B) extends Tag


  def match_?(criterias: Set[Criteria], tags: Set[Tag]) : Boolean = {
    !criterias.exists {
      case ACriteria(v) => !v.map(value => ATag(value)).exists(tags.contains)
      case BCriteria(v) => !v.map(value => BTag(value)).exists(tags.contains)
    }
  }

  println(match_?(Set(ACriteria(Set(A1, A2))), Set(ATag(A1), ATag(A2)))) // true
  println(match_?(Set(ACriteria(Set(A1))), Set(ATag(A1), ATag(A2)))) // true
  println(match_?(Set(ACriteria(Set(A1, A2))), Set(ATag(A1)))) // true
  println(match_?(Set(), Set(ATag(A1)))) // true
  println(match_?(Set(ACriteria(Set(A1))), Set())) // false
  println(match_?(Set(ACriteria(Set(A1)), BCriteria(Set(B1))), Set(ATag(A1)))) // false
  println(match_?(Set(ACriteria(Set(A1)), BCriteria(Set(B1))), Set(BTag(B1)))) // false

}
```

But it's verbose, not really DRY code in the match method.

**[update]** when I think about it, it seems that types `Criteria` and `Tags` are not very useful. Here is a simpler version, but also with lower type-checking due to `Any`. Any way to fix that (maybe `Coproduct`) ?

```
object Criteria6 extends App {

  // Features
  // Feature A
  trait A
  case object A1 extends A
  case object A2 extends A

  // Feature B
  trait B
  case object B1 extends B
  case object B2 extends B

  def match_?(criterias: Set[Set[Any]], tags: Set[Any]) : Boolean = {
    !criterias.exists {
      v => !v.exists(tags.contains)
    }
  }

  println(match_?(Set(Set(A1, A2)), Set(A1, A2))) // true
  println(match_?(Set(Set(A1)), Set(A1, A2))) // true
  println(match_?(Set(Set(A1, A2)), Set(A1))) // true
  println(match_?(Set(), Set(A1))) // true
  println(match_?(Set(Set(A1)), Set())) // false
  println(match_?(Set(Set(A1), Set(B1)), Set(A1))) // false
  println(match_?(Set(Set(A1), Set(B1)), Set(B1))) // false
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish here. Given what you have, I would replace Criteria and Tag instances with a Type Parameter. Say, `case class Tag[T](t: T)`.

Answer (score 0):

So [Type parameters](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/generic-classes.html) seem to be what you want.

```
object Criteria6 extends App {

  // Features
  // Feature A
  trait A
  case object A1 extends A
  case object A2 extends A

  // Feature B
  trait B
  case object B1 extends B
  case object B2 extends B

  def match_?[T](criterias: Set[Set[T]], tags: Set[T]) : Boolean = {
    !criterias.exists {
      v => !v.exists(tags.contains)
    }
  }

  println(match_?(Set(Set(A1, A2)), Set(A1, A2))) // true
  println(match_?(Set(Set(A1)), Set(A1, A2))) // true
  println(match_?(Set(Set(A1, A2)), Set(A1))) // true
  println(match_?(Set(), Set(A1))) // true
  println(match_?(Set(Set(A1)), Set())) // false
  println(match_?(Set(Set(A1), Set(B1)), Set(A1))) // false
  println(match_?(Set(Set(A1), Set(B1)), Set(B1))) // false
}
```

This will have the added benefit that you will not be able to call `match_?` with mismatched Types (A or B).

What I still don't get is what is `Set(Set(A1, A2)), Set(A1, A2))` supposed to represent that requires validation...